# Convert a string with a double number on it, into a double number

Tags: c

I have the string `temp[256]` and inside it there's a double number, such as `0.125` and such, and everything is going well though some times it gets a number that's too big for a double number, like `0.888888888888888888888888888888888888888883`, and the double number only holds like 7 numbers instead of all.

I've been using the `atof` to convert the string into the double, but I think the problem is the double here, because it doesn't have enough space for all the numbers....
This is what I wrote :

```
char temp[256]; // Has the number inside it
double temp_num = 0; // need to put the string inside this variable
temp_num = atof(temp);
printf ("%f\n", temp_num);
```

the output from the print is fine as long as the number isn't larger then 7 digits after the zero, but if it's a number like `0.8815818188888888888888888888888888888888888888888143`, it only prints me the 7 first digits, like in this example it'll print `8815818` instead of the whole number...
so I guess I need a bigger variable ?

Comment: try `printf( "%lf\n", temp_num )` or `%Lf`

Comment: @Amit: Did you run the sample I posted in your other question? If you want to *display* more digits after the decimal point, just use a width specifier in `printf` such as this: `printf( "extracted value = %.16f\n", d );`. I tested the sample I had posted with the input string you provided there (and here) and it works fine.

Comment: @AmitM9S5, I agree with dirkgently's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printf have a default behavior of printing only 7 digits after the zero when dealing with doubles or floats however you can change that behavior and control how many numbers after the zero printf prints like this

```
printf ("%.20f\n", temp_num);
```

Here you get 20 digits after the zero.

For more details please refer to:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/
2. The c programming language second edition.

Comment: Thanks, but does it mean that inside temp_num theres 20 digits after the zero, even if I dont print it, right ?
so it's like, showing me 7 digits after the zero only because it's the basic print of a double, but it still has 20 digits after the zero ?

Comment: @AmitM9S6 the default behavior of printf is printing only 7 digits after the zero. using .20 doesn't mean that you have 20 digits in temp_num. i suggest you to read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Q: Thanks, but does it mean that inside temp_num theres 20 digits after the zero?  A: No! It means nothing of the kind!!!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: so How can I get inside temp_num those 20 digits ?

Comment: oh, so it's just that a normal printf can only print 7 numbers after the zero , and using the method u said can make me print more then 7 digits...

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1) I prefer ["sscanf()"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) over "atof()": it allows you to check for conversion errors (i.e. illegal numbers).

2)  As [dirkgently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently%27s_Holistic_Detective_Agency)  already said, you can ["format"](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html) any floating point value - restricting the #/digits,etc, with a "format string".

Comment: simply `temp_num = sscanf(temp);` will convert temp into temp_num ?